# "Determining your root organisation units" in DHIS2

Tags: dhis2, java

When wanting to create a 'Organisation unit group', instead of it showing me the organisation tree, it says 'Determining your root organisation units' without showing any of my Organisation Unit.

Where's the bug?

Comment: I have similar problem, when i try to use dhis2-live standalone application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is happening to you. When I go to https://play.dhis2.org/demo and try to create an organisation unit group, it shows me:

[image: screen shot]

I wonder if you have valid root organisation unit on your account. Try going to users, edit your user account, and make sure a root organisation unit is selected for your account.

Comment: And make sure only ONE orgunit is selected.